# Sage Pay Payment Failure in Magento

Tags: magento, opayo

I am setting up a megento shop but while testing I get the following error when paying by card using ebizmarts Sage Pay module:

> Payment has failed, please reload checkout page and try again. Your card has not been charged.

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a support forum for the free plugin here http://ebizmarts.com/forums and if you are using the PRO module, you can just use the contact form here http://ebizmarts.com/contact-us

Also, the problem you mention is described on the Wiki here http://wiki.ebizmarts.com/sage-pay-common-problems

Answer (score 1):

**FIXED**

From what I can see and for whatever reason, Magento was loading the "info.phtml" file from the theme/default/checkout/onepage/review folder, rather than the one in the sagepaysuite folder.

I copied in the above code to the relevant position to the default info.html file, and it's working now.

The staging server was loading the sagepaysuite/checkout/review/info.phtml file correctly, hence it was working.